# conditionally hide/removing templated data before it is injected into the dom?

Tags: javascript

Basically at the moment I have 2 buttons that both use the same template to get JSON data and then display the templated content in the same div, clearing the HTML and inserting as required. My problem is that 1 button requires me to present position numbers `<span class="positionNumber">'+i+'</span>` whereas the other doesn't, is there a way I can add or remove this from the template based on the button selected with a conditional or something like that?

**JS**

```
var template = '<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+data.feed[i].code+'" class="videoEntry videoBg'+i+'" target="_blank"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+data.feed[i].code+'/0.jpg" alt="'+data.feed[i].title+'" class="videoThumb" /><span class="positionNumber">'+i+'</span><h2>'+data.feed[i].title+'</h2></a>';
```

Comment: Are you able to edit the template? Or when it's being accessed, do you know in your code which button was pressed?

Comment: hey yeah i know what button is pressed and i also have access to edit the template

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its overkill for this but have you tried the jquery tmpl plugin.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/

you can specify if statements within your template along the lines of

```
{{if ${i}}} <span class="positionNumber">'+i+'</span> {{/if}}
```

if i isn't set then the span tag wont appear.

Edit: Alternatively check i and append the template string accordingly when required.

```
var template = '<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+data.feed[i].code+'" class="videoEntry videoBg'+i+'" target="_blank"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+data.feed[i].code+'/0.jpg" alt="'+data.feed[i].title+'" class="videoThumb" />';
        if (typeof i != 'undefined'){
            template += '<span class="positionNumber">'+i+'</span>';
        }
        template += <h2>'+data.feed[i].title+'</h2></a>';
```

Comment: yeah i kind of thought it may be overkill using a templating plugin since i really dont have to template that much but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Same suggestion as the other answer (to edit the template), but maybe a cleaner approach would be to use the ternary operator:

```
var template = '<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+data.feed[i].code+'" class="videoEntry videoBg'+i+'" target="_blank"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+data.feed[i].code+'/0.jpg" alt="'+data.feed[i].title+'" class="videoThumb" />' + (typeof i == undefined ? '<span class="positionNumber">'+i+'</span>' : '') + '<h2>'+data.feed[i].title+'</h2></a>';
```